# WPF [External Code] calling business object properties

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF App with XAML front end and business rules objects.
Running inside the VS 2019 IDE (16.2.3), sudden exceptions are triggered in methods/properties inside my business objects.
When i run the app standalone, apparently WPF eats those exceptions.
When i try to look at the Call STack, it shows [External Code] so no way to find which component is the culprit. or is it possible?

This was not happening before, it started as of new late releases of VS.
When the exception happens, the object had been instantiated and there is some null data because somehow the constructor is called. 
The object called are always connected to the XAML through {Binding} but in other properties, not the ones which produce the exception.

It is hard to reproduce, because happens at random during the development environmnent execution.

Just found an instance where it always happens (the form has a button with a ToolTip with x:Static binded text)

1. Open the form.
2. Hover to show the ToolTip
3. When the ToolTip disappears, an exception is thrown in a totally unrelated object (which is albeit binded in the XAML form)
4. if I press Continue, that exception is not propagated to any part of my code, it just continues.

after that first occurrence, it does not appear again.

HOw can i inspect which component/thread, etc. called the property/method?
If this is by design, how can i prevent VS this annoying behavior of stopping randomly at exceptions not related to the actual code?
thxs

Comment: Have you used any Third-party controls in UI. You can try binding a sample data from the codebehind or VM and see if there same error is throwing if so it will be related to your control or binding.

Comment: You must garantuate that object passed to WPF are thread safe. If it is not it will randomly crash when will WPF and your code accessing the same thing at the same time. Showing External Code in call stack is caused because enabled `Just my code` feature in settings (use Ctrl + Q to search and disable it) but as you have pointed It will probably point somewhere into .NET framework code.

Comment: Visual Studio have lot of tool for debuging multithread applications. Search for Threads window, there you can switch to debug another thread. Diagnostics tool with Intellitrace shows first change extensions which could be usefull for you. In Exceptions window you can mark all CLR exceptions to break program when any exception occur with no matter if the exception is handled (by you or .NET framework) or unhandled. It will stop program and enbale yout to debug it everytime whean any exception somewhere occur.